# How can I add functionalities to Sublime Text 2?

Tags: plugins, scripting, editor, text-editor, sublimetext

I recently discovered this [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) editor, and since I love to code with it, I would like to add more custom functionalities to it.

Is it possible to use some scripting language to enhance its core features? I found some python references on the main folder, but I didn't find anything useful in the documentation on the official site. I guess the editor is written in Python?

Until now I managed only to add custom snippets, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out anyway, looks like I didn't look well enough in the [docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-basics).